# How to select file using selenium webdriver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am on Ubuntu 13. I want to select a file and upload. On selection of file, it uploads that file. 
I am using the following code:

```
butt1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='divIcon']/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a")
butt1.click()
butt1.send_keys(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/samsung_icon_img.png")
```

It opens windows window, types path (`/var/www/Website/File`), but never searches for the file and keeps the window opened forever.

It does not throw any error either. Please help if I am missing anything.

Comment: i think you should provide more code to your post.

Comment: I want to upload file by clicking on button with code:
<a class="btn_icon_add cmn_icon _default_iconimg" flow-drag-leave="style={}" flow-drag-enter="style={opacity: '0.2'}" flow-drop="" flow-btn="" href="javascript:void(0);">

This is my code:
if os.path.isfile("res_img.jpg"):
resize_img("res_img.jpg","samsung_icon_img.png", (512,512))
butt1.send_keys(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/samsung_icon_img.png")

which opens an OS level dialog box, where I'm getting stuck. It doesnot search for the file and keep on this dialog box.

Comment: Post the code in your question - code in comment is almost impossible to read.